# How to make a Bash script that in a loop: reads a command from a list-of-commands file, paste it into terminal, execute that command, goes on

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

Given a list of Bash commands, written into a file, one per line,
I would like to make a Bash script that does the following things in a loop:

1. reads a command from a list-of-commands file,
2. paste it into terminal,
3. execute that command (= presses enter),
4. goes on with the next command until it reaches the end of the list

Is it possible to do it with bash?

Otherwise I think I have to develop a script in another language that pastes commands into an active istance of the terminal (or [Terminator](https://terminator-gtk3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)), presses enter.

How can I do it?

### Note:

Some of the commands written into the file are `ssh` commands (`ssh user@machine_ip` and `logout`),
thus, the commands on the list are to be executed on different machines.

So I cannot achieve the aim by simply putting these commands in a bash script and running it, because as the `ssh` command resolves, the script logs into another machine, and the subsequent commands would be "set in pause" until the user disconnects from the remote machine.

Furthermore, in my case I have to log into certain machines by necessarily doing a ssh tunnel through 3 or 4 machines, so I do not want to use the `ssh` command following syntax

```
ssh -o ConnectTimeout=$ssh_timeout $user_B@$remote_machine_B_ip                         \
              "sudo -i -u user_O ssh -o ConnectTimeout=$ssh_timeout $user_O@$remote_machine_P_ip  \
                  \"ssh -o ConnectTimeout=$ssh_timeout $user_O@$remote_machine_C_ip               \
                      \"bash /tmp/script1.sh\"                                          \
                  \"                                                                              \
              "
```

because it gets too much complex and fragile/difficult to be interpreted/edited by other developers.

Comment: Consider use of `-J` ***proxy***:  `ssh -Juser_O@$remote_machine_B_ip,user_O@$remote_machine_P_ip user_O@$remote_machine_C_ip bash /tmp/script1.sh`

Comment: You may want to consider [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect).

Comment: @Dzienny can you please make an example applying expect to the procedure in the question?

Comment: "a list of Bash commands, written into a file, one per line" isn't that a very good (free) description for a "bash script"?? And doesn't it behave exactly like 1.-4., when you "execute it"?

Comment: hi @xerx593, please read the Note, it explains why a bash script does not meet my needs.

Comment: ok, get you..but also just a matter of "perspective" and "syntax" (quoting!). (considering "bash" can spawn "new bashes", (also background (`&`) processes) and "pipe" in/out/err..streams...